# How to add or remove borders in navigation menu?

Tags: menus, themes, css, navigation, html

One probably very simple CSS question for you guys.

I'm building a new site for myself and I wanted to divide each menu item with a vertical line, which I managed to do by finding the CSS selector in Firefox dev tools:

```
.is-frontend #content-holder .semplice-navbar nav ul li{
    border-right: solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

That looks like this (and as you can see I circled out the culprit):

### [image: I'd like to get rid of the border-right line as seen in the red circle]

Now, the problem is: I just cannot find a CSS selector that's only for that last menu item. I can create one in the Rules section of the Dev tools like this:

```
element{
border:none;
}
```

which basically creates an inline style attribute in the html... Like so:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-345" style="border: none;">
```

Do you have an idea how could I remove the last vertical line (border)?
I don't have a child theme (was thinking of changing theme/html code), but I'm still a beginner with WP... Surely there's an easier solution?

If you want to take a look at the site, it's pass protected, but the menu should be there.
[magmaworks.net](http://magmaworks.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS 3, you can use the :last-child or :last-of-type selectors:

`.is-frontend #content-holder .semplice-navbar nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}`

However, you could flip this around to make it more backwards compatible using :first-child (which is available in CSS2):

`.is-frontend #content-holder .semplice-navbar nav ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}`

`.is-frontend #content-holder .semplice-navbar nav ul li:first-child {
    border-right: none;
}`